# Spring's IOC with annotations is confusing for a Guice guy. Help to enlighten me

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container, guice

I came into IOC via Google Guice.

And now I've been forced to use Spring 2.5.6 at work & I am lost because Spring is quite complicated. Here are some questions after reading bits of the spring docs:

- What is the difference between `@Service`, `@Controller` and `@Component` ? If I just want to auto wire my objects like Guice, do I need to be bothered by all these stereotypes ?
- I'm planning to go the component-scan route with only constructor injection (Setter injection is mostly advocated by the Church of Scientology) and no freaking XML stuff. So is this code extract all I need ?

  ```
  @Component
  public class Foo
  {
      @Autowired(required=true)
      public Foo( Bar bar, @Qualifier("yay") Boo yay, 
                  @Qualifier("hoo") Boo hoo )
      {
          _bar = bar; _boo = boo;
      }

      Bar _bar;
      Boo _boo;
  ....snipped...
  }

  @Component
  @Qualifier("yay")
  @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
  public BooYay implements Boo
  {
  }

  @Component
  @Qualifier("hoo")
  @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
  public BooHoo implements Boo
  {
  }
  ```

  - In the above example, did I correctly qualify the 2 different implementations of `Boo` ?
  - Is there any feature similar to Google Guice's Providers ?
  - How do I mimic the `@Singleton` behaviour (in Guice) in Spring ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems all fine and your components will get `autowired`. You must give your package name in XML config file, so Spring can scan that for annotations.

Spring-managed components in general, the default and most common scope for autodetected components is singleton.

Actually, @Component is a generalisation of @Service and @Controller. See the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html).

> Spring 2.5 introduces further
>   stereotype annotations: @Component,
>   @Service and @Controller. @Component
>   serves as a generic stereotype for any
>   Spring-managed component; whereas,
>   @Repository, @Service, and @Controller
>   serve as specializations of @Component
>   for more specific use cases (e.g., in
>   the persistence, service, and
>   presentation layers, respectively).
>   What this means is that you can
>   annotate your component classes with
>   @Component, but by annotating them
>   with @Repository, @Service, or
>   @Controller instead, your classes are
>   more properly suited for processing by
>   tools or associating with aspects. For
>   example, these stereotype annotations
>   make ideal targets for pointcuts. Of
>   course, it is also possible that
>   @Repository, @Service, and @Controller
>   may carry additional semantics in
>   future releases of the Spring
>   Framework. Thus, if you are making a
>   decision between using @Component or
>   @Service for your service layer,
>   @Service is clearly the better choice.
>   Similarly, as stated above,
>   @Repository  is already supported as a
>   marker for automatic exception
>   translation in your persistence layer.

Make sure that your `default-autowire` or `autowire` value for those beans is `byType`. And then you should modify your Boo components like below,

```
@Component("yay")
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public BooYay implements Boo
{...}


@Component("hoo")
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public BooHoo implements Boo
{...}
```

You might like to do it with `autowire = "byName"`, in that case you will not need `@Qualifiers`, but have to provide the matching setters. I hope you will managed to knock the thing off now.

Comment: It is not working. All of the constructor args are null although the logs show that it is scanning & identifying the beans. What are potential mistakes ?

Comment: whats your `default-autowire` value?

Comment: I'm currently working in a Jersey-Spring environment. It seems like I need to use a Jersey specific annotation to get autowire to work. This is too clunky for me. So I'm abandoning Spring and going back to Guice (which currently works just fine). My first forays into Spring just left a bad taste in my mouth.